# undefined in parameter function. when should it be used?

Tags: javascript

I saw some javaScript, like [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) written in this way:

```
( function( undefined ) {
    "use strict";
        // some code
})();
```

My question is: When should undefined parameter be used?
Always or in special circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time when you see that pattern they are ensuring that 'undefined' is truly undefined.  See how at the bottom they don't pass any arguments.

This is a self executing function and you can pass parameters to it.

> ```
> (function(undefined) {  // no parameters are passed in so undefined is undefined.
>  "use strict";
>
> })(/*no parameters passed*/)
> ```

If your code is using undefined and you need to ensure that some other javascript library doesn't alter the meaning of undefined then you would want to use this pattern.  However, this is not something that commonly occurs, it is just a safety net.  For some reason in javascript 'undefined' can be set a value just like any other variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway my question is should always undefined parameter be used. If not when?

Comment: @LorraineBernard -- Depends on how paranoid you are.  On my website, I don't use random 3rd party code and the few libraries I do use are very well behaved, so I don't use that pattern.  If you are writing snippits of JS that may be included into random pages not under your control, then you may want a higher level of coding paranoia.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, `undefined` is not a special keyword.  It is a regular, global variable.

If `undefined` gets changed by outside code, it can cause weird bugs.  Some people declare an unused parameter in their function declarations of `undefined` so the function will have a variable called `undefined` with the known value of `undefined`.

`var undefined` in the function body does the same thing, but requires a few more bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway my question is should always undefined parameter be used. If not when?

Comment: Whenever you are worried that someone may have mucked with `undefined.`  It depends on if you are in full control of your code or if your code is mixed-and-matched with possibly broken/hostile code.